# RCV Polling Data from Google Forms goes the wrong direction in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, google-forms

I am making an RCV voting system in Google Forms, however, when the results go into Google Sheets, they come out like this:

| Timestamp | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 239029339 | Candidate A | Candidate B | Candidate D | Candidate C |
| 903493404 | Candidate D | Candidate C | Candidate A | Candidate B |

When I want them to be like this:

| Timestamp | Candidate A | Candidate B | Candidate C | Candidate D |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 239029339 | 1 | 2 | 4 | 3 |
| 903493404 | 3 | 4 | 2 | 1 |

How can I do that in Google Sheets?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you're probably using the Multiple Choice Grid question in Google forms.  If that's true, you can put the Candidate Names as the 'Rows' and the the choice number as the 'Columns'.  This would feed it into the attached Google Sheet as you would like it to be.